# How to make sure that user inputs just one name?

Tags: jquery, input

I want to make sure that user inputed exactly one name (first name, or last name, but not both or none), and at the same time to make sure the inputed name  is longer than 3 chars.

I have tried to do it but there is a collision between leaving it empty and making it 2 chars more.

This is my code:

```
if ($("#firstName").val().length > 0 && $("#lastName").val().length > 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#error").slideDown().text("You may enter just first name or last name");
    return;
} else if ($("#firstName").val().length <= 2 || $("#lastName").val().length <= 2) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#error").slideDown().text("Your name have to contain at least 3 letters");
    return;
}
```

The fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mzu28nkv/16/)

Comment: A first name can be only two characters, same goes for a last name.

Answer (score 1):

Check if space is present in the name. If present then user has entered full name

Try this:

```
var name = $.trim($('#firstName').val());
if (name.length < 3 && name.indexOf(' ') > -1) {
    alert("Invalid Name; Enter first name or last name only");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi You should change your condition little bit. Its a bit lengthy, but serves the purpose.

```
if ($("#firstName").val().length > 0 && $("#lastName").val().length > 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#error").slideDown().text("You may enter just first name or last name");
    return;
}

if($("#firstName").val().length > 0){
   if ($("#firstName").val().length <= 2){
     event.preventDefault();
     $("#error").slideDown().text("Your first name have to contain at least 3 letters");  
      return;
    }  
}

if($("#lastName").val().length > 0){
   if ($("#lastName").val().length <= 2){
       event.preventDefault();
      $("#error").slideDown().text("Your last name have to contain at least 3 letters");  
      return;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#firstName").val().length > 0 && $("#lastName").val().length > 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#error").slideDown().text("You may enter just first name or last name");
    return;
} else if ($("#firstName").val().length <= 2 || $("#lastName").val().length <= 2) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#error").slideDown().text("Your name have to contain at least 3 letters");
    return;
}
```

You check for both fields entered. Then you check if either field is <=2.
Latter is true even if only one name was entered and the other left empty.
You should check like this

```
if ($("#firstName").val().length > 0 && $("#lastName").val().length > 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#error").slideDown().text("You may enter just first name or last name");
    return;
} else if (!($("#firstName").val().length > 2 || $("#lastName").val().length > 2)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#error").slideDown().text("Your name have to contain at least 3 letters");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Karthiks version should actually work better, since it distinguishes cases better

Comment: Thanks. I would be glad if you could tell me why if I input numbers my "first name" for exmaple i get error (because i did "isNumeric"), but if I put letters with numbers (for exmaple "asdahsd123123"), it passes. thanks

Comment: Cause isNummeric fails when the string is alphanummeric. it only tests if the string can be interpretet as an actual numeric. If you are familar with regex, that would be easiest to test for numbers, if not you need to write a small parser funktion for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robinat130/fmtef0w2/1/)
I hope this is exactly what you are looking for,

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {


    // TODO 1: Make sure age has only digits

    // TODO 2: Make sure names do not have digits

    // TODO 3: Make the email is valid (has @ and . inside of them - do not use RegEx, use indexOf)

    // TODO 4: Make sure each name is longer than 2 chars if the input is not empty
     if (!$("#firstName").val() && !$("#lastName").val()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#error").slideDown().text("You may enter first name or last name");
        return;
    }else  if ($.isNumeric($('#firstName').val()) || $.isNumeric($('#lastName').val())) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#error").slideDown().text("Your name can contain letters only");
        return;
    }else if (!($("#firstName").val().length > 2 || $("#lastName").val().length > 2)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#error").slideDown().text("Your name have to contain at least 3 letters");
    return;
}

     if ($("#email").val().indexOf("@") < 0 || $("#email").val().lastIndexOf(".") < 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#error").slideDown();
        $("#error").text("Your Email is not valid.");
        return;
    }
    if ($("#age").val() == "" || $("#age").val() < 18) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#error").slideDown().text("You must be over 18 to register");
        return;
    }


    if (!$.isNumeric($('#age').val())) {


        event.preventDefault();
        $("#error").slideDown().text("Your age can contain numbers only");
        return;
    }




    if (!$("#terms").is(":checked")) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#error").slideDown().text("Please accept terms");
        return;
    }    


     $("#error").slideDown().text("we can now submit the form");




        // TODO 5: Make sure the user inputed excacly one name (first name, or last name, but not both or non)
    });
```